# Activate nav when the page is open

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

The system I am currently making has a lot of pages. So I was thinking of including a single file of Nav bar to include on each page. But I can't change the class of the active Nav. I tried a code I also found here but since the Nav are linked to actual pages, the "active" nav doesn't stay active. By the way, here's my new code, but I can't make it work.

```
<ul class="nav" id="main-menu">
   <li>
      <a href="index.php">Dashboard</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="manage_user.php">Manage Users</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="view_user.php">View Users</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="assign_role.php">Assign Roles</a>
   </li>
   <li>
     ....
```

Here's my jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).on('click', '.nav li', function() {
      $(".nav li").removeClass("active-menu");
      $('ul.nav > li > a[href^="' + document.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active-menu');
   });
</script>
```

Comment: you can add a class to `body` on each page e.g. `<body class="viewusersbody">` and add a class to each `li` e.g. '<li class="viewusersli">'. Then on page load, get the body class, replace body by 'li', and you have the class of the li which needs to be activated. You can `trigger` click event on this. I'd prefer to use `id` instead of `class` though.

Comment: Okay I will try that. Thanks